Can an aggregate just depend on the ID of another aggregate for its own identity?
I started writing my application with a very understandable assumption that every Aggregate should be represented by a root entity that has its own ID (a surrogate key). But I think I have found a situation where there is no need to have a surrogate key as my aggregate is fully identifiable via another attribute that is a natural occurring key in the aggregate. Below is a high level understanding of the specs of my personal app:
I'm building an application where a user can upload photos. More specifically, a user can have up to 3 uploaded photos at any one point. So to enforce this invariance, I have created an aggregate called UserPhotosAggregate with the following high level code:
class UserPhotosAggregate extends Aggregate {
  private userId: UserId;
  private photos: Photo[] = [];

  constructor(userId: UserId) {
    this.userId = userId;
  }

  addPhoto(p: Photo[]) {
    // adds photo to array if there are less than 3 photos
  }
  
  deletePhoto(pId: PhotoId) {
    // removes photo form this.photos array if present
  }
}

This makes a lot of sense to me. I see no need though to put an ID that is unique to this aggregate but rather I'm using the UserId attribute to do so. The aggregate here has been developed to enforce the invariance but carries no semantic meaning to a user nor business owner. In addition, the aggregate boundary is fully identifiable via the userId.
And the repository for this sort of class can look like the following:
class UserPhotosAggregateRepository extends Repository {
  load(userId: UserId): UserPhotosAggregateRepository {
    // do db things to load a UserPhotosAggregate
  }
}

How does this type of design look like to you? Is it severely flawed to use the ID of one aggregate, (i.e UserId from UserAggregate) to define another aggregate (UserPhotosAggregate)? Please give me your thoughts here. I'd appreciate rationale and not just a rule of thumb answer.

You should just have User as your object, with the photos, id and anything else

But wouldn't that lack cohesion? I say this as the user creation and its concerns are one thing while managing scheduling concerns are another?

UserPhotosAggregate extends Aggregate is a bad idea. If UserPhotos is an aggregate in the domain model, then still call it UserPhotos and reserve inheritance to domain-specific "is-a" relationships. Mixing this up with inheritance in a technical dimension (extends Aggregate  - where "Aggregate" is not a domain term, but a technical DDD term) will sonner or later lead to modeling issues.

... you find more information in this article or this SWE.SE answer of mine about that article.

What is the design consideration behind UserPhotos, i.e. the collection of one user's photos, instead of UserPhoto, i.e. a specific photo uploaded by a user?

@DocBrown I don't disagree with your point but there are (in some languages at least) innocent use cases for this, e.g. as a generic type constraint. Using C# as an example: GenericRepository<TAggregate> where TAggregate : Aggregate, so as to avoid silly usages of TAggregate such as primitive types. Maybe not very necessary but I wouldn't call it harmful either.

@Flater: in your example, Aggregate could be an interface! And that is ok, since it does not restrict semantic inheritance, In the OPs questiion, Aggregate is a class and UserPhotosAggregate  uses class inheritance. That's a bad idea (in most cases).

Not everything needs to be an Entity. You also have value objects and services, and you can potentially introduce additional concepts. To me, this looks conceptually like a value object (e.g. if you had two lists, each with the same set of photos, it wouldn't matter to your application logic or to your users which one you were using, or if you discarded the other one). What do these photos represent? Something like a profile picture?

I think you are overcomplicating this and moving away from the core concept of DDD which is to match your code to the way the business thinks.
No one is saying "A UserAggregate has a UserPhotoAggregate with up to 3 Photos"
They are saying "a User can have up to 3 uploaded Photos at any one point
You just have the one Aggregate Root, User
class User
{
   string id
   BinaryData[] uploadedPhotos
}

With the logic to prevent more than 3 photos
Now you might hit some performance issues that would get you to change the binary data to ids, or you might find the object gets too big and you want to split the logic into services etc. etc.
But your Domain language will match the requirements', you won't ever be pushing back on requirements with "Ahh but I can't do that because the UserPhotoAgrewhatssit has a natural key and that means..."
You might think that this won't happen, but I can see some already.

"We deleted all these users but the database is still taking up loads of diskspace!?"
"Oh you have to also delete the UserPhotoAggregates, when you said 'make a function to delete a User' I just deleted the user"

"I made a new user and it already has some photos?!?"
"Oh maybe an old user had the same id and now its picking up their photos from the userphotoaggreegate, you didn't say to clear existing photos when making a new user"



Thank so much for your take. Makes a lot of sense. Its true that all the user can do is upload a photo for now, but what if they can do more in the future? Would I then shove more relations in the same aggregate? Wouldn't that go against the mindset of making your aggregates as small as possible? It would also go against modelling against invariance boundaries would it not? In my system, a user can sign up with their info but the uploading photo part would come later, although its the main operation. So uploading a photo has nothing to do with user creation. Does that change anything?

These are all vague potential problems. Maybe they will change the best solution, but until you actually hit one of them you won't know. Even then, you won't want to move your design away from the Domain Language.

@alaboudi Ewan is correct that future "might be" scenarios shouldn't always drive your design today. However, the underlying spark of your question is reasonable, in that there is some kind of common sense limit on how much you can/should/would want to stack into a single aggregate, even if each individual piece can be argued to belong to the aggregate. But that's a nuanced decisions for which you're not going to find an objective answer as everyone will draw that line differently.


Can an aggregate just depend on the ID of another aggregate for its own identity?

Based on DDD guidelines, the short answer here is no.
One caveat I'll point out is that an argument can be made for a composite identifier, i.e. one that is made up as a combination of several FK aggregate IDs, but that's not relevant for your current scenario.

There are several ways to tackle this problem. Other answers have addressed different parts of your current scenario.
I want to tackle the overall goal of UserPhotos as an aggregate.
Following DDD guidelines an aggregate is something that stands on its own. It justifies its own existence. As an early hint, the fact that you call it UserPhotos already suggests that you're thinking of this belonging to a user, not as an independent concept on its own.
But that's a bit of a semantical argument, as you might have called it PhotoCollection instead. So let's roll with that idea.
I'm still not a fan of this approach, because the nature of the collection is inherently to keep all of a single user's photos together in a single collection. Which again hints that you're looking at this from a user-centric perspective, which detracts from your proposal that this is a separate aggregate.
However, Photo would be a more reasonable suggestion for an aggregate (but not a guarantee, I will counter this point later on). On a technical level, not much changes.

Just like how your photo collection holds a FK to the user, your photo can just have the same FK.
In terms of blocking the 4th photo upload, it doesn't really matter whether you load the collection (where userId = @userId), or you load all photos (where userId = @userId). In either case, you'll be loading all of the user's existing photos in order to confirm that they haven't exceeded their daily quota.

What does change, however, is that the user ID is no longer the PK for your photo, since you can have multiple photos for the same user. The photo should have its own ID as part of its own lifecycle. This is the essence of what makes an aggregate an aggregate.

This is the part where things get hairy. Some people will say that if a photo can never exist without a user, that it therefore cannot exist as an aggregate on its own. That's not an incorrect reading of DDD guidelines, but there are limits to that kind of assertion.
In the example of a video rental store application, you can easily understand that Customer and Video are aggregates. However, where should Rental go? Obviously, it can't exist without a Customer and a Video. But generally speaking this is still an aggregate on its own because it has its own set of operations that you perform on it. While in the process of having a customer check out a video, you're not altering the customer or the video, you're focused on registering the rental that's taking place (or similarly when the customer returns the video).
The pragmatic approach here is that it's okay for an aggregate to mandate the existence of another aggregate, if and where it makes reasonable sense (e.g. needing an actual customer and and actual video in order for a customer to be able to rent a video). The reason for making Rental its own aggregate is because it contains a set of operations and overall business/domain logic that centers on the rental, not necessarily the customer's details (nor the video's details).
So, in that same spirit, you could take the hardline stance here and make photos part of the user, or you could take the pragmatic approach and define the photo as an aggregate on its own, but with a hard requirement that it must refer to an existing user.
As part of the "a customer can't upload more than three photos" rule, you don't actually need to load user data. The user ID sufficiently identifies the user in order for you to be able to count how many photos there are for this user ID.

If you have two entities X and Y, it is often worth asking the questions:
If X didn't exist would it still make sense to have Y?
If Y didn't exist would it still make sense to have X?

In your case I think we should examine three "entities":

A User
A Photo
A (User) Photo Collection / Aggregate

Lets start with Photo's - it may make sense to make each photo their own aggregate, simply because most business logic doesn't care about the content of a photo - or more specifically, it typically doesn't validate the photo beyond metadata (does the photo exists / how many photos do we have).
Hence for most business logic functions we just need an ID of the photo (the lack of such an ID indicates we don't have a photo). Additionally from an implementation standpoint photos are typically stored in some kind of blob store ** then the Path/ID (used to access the blob store) is placed in the database. Typically the only time the actual content is needed, is when the photo needs to be displayed to a human.
** - When I say blob store here, I don't mean a blob in the database I mean a service like S3, however any storage system is fine as long as it provides HA.

So lets assume you have broken out photos into their own aggregate/service and for the core logic we only have (photo) ID's.
Your UserPhotosAggregate is now just a container for 2-4 ID's (the User ID, plus 1-3 Photo ID's).
If Photo's didn't exist would it still make sense to have UserPhotosAggregate?

Clearly not, all you have is a User Id.
If User's didn't exist would it still make sense to have UserPhotosAggregate?

Maybe, Collections of photos are a thing, they can have meaning (all photos of a sporting event) however in your case there is no additional functionality, so again I don't think the aggregate makes sense.
Given this, I think it makes sense to collapse the UserPhotosAggregate into one of the other two aggregates:

A User can have a collection of PhotoID's
A Photo can have an "owner" UserID


It is also possible that there may be additional metadata about a photo - such as: This is a headshot or this is a picture of the users passport, you could include metadata in either of the other aggregates - I think which one is going to depend upon the business requirements (need to access this data from other services).


Can an aggregate just depend on the ID of another aggregate for its own identity?

Getting "all semantic" for a moment, an ID is not just a number it is both a number and a type (Class), with this definition even if you re-use the number when you clarify what you want (specify the type) you end up with different IDs.
So does it make sense to re-use the same number to lookup two different types? Maybe? for example you might have separate Customer and Manager entities. Then choose to reuse the same (numeric) ID - if a manager buys a product from the store. But this feels like tight coupling for the the sake of it - I am not sure, if there is strong benefit from re-using ID's across types.
In the more general case (User vs UsersPhotoCollection) this seems to be a case of splitting one aggregate into smaller pieces, again I can't identify a specific advantage to doing this.

I must be getting old, still storing photos on disk and then a location on disk in the database as disk storage is faster and cheaper than databases :) I'd contest that a collection without photos is useless. It may be a temporary state (collection created but not yet filled, or last photo removed), or you may create one automatically on creating a user (maybe "favourites" they can flag over other peoples' work).

Updated answer to clarify "blob storage".

My answer expressed no opinion with respect to if it makes sense to create a collection class (for Photo ID's) my point was that such a class isn't an aggregate, I would go further and say that it's probably a value object.

I'd myself create it as something like collection-id, collection-owner-id, collection-description, , [possibly other convenience fields related to display preferences].

@jwenting (a) "database" is vague, not every database provider has the same performance profile for bulk data storage (b) the simplicity from having a single infrastructural component can outweigh the benefits of having two separate components (database and disk) (c) cloud-based considerations tend not to rely on disk-based access. There are persistence technologies that try to closely resemble the same overall experience (e.g. blob stores) but depending on where the original data is stored (e.g. a doc db), the gains from having a separate blob store might not be very big.

@Flater I'm that old, back from when the performance impact of any database engine we tested wasn't on par with file system retrieval :)
